# why is the limit of this product not equal to the product of the limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

the $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x\cos x}{\sin x} = 1$, 
but $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x \cdot \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{-\sin x}{\cos x} = 0 \cdot 0 = 0$ using product of limits and  L'hospital's rule. Why is this incorrect?

(thanks Erik for the formatting)

Comment: Because $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ doesn't exist. L'Hospital is not applicable.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. This is really hard to read.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$ is not an indeterminate form - it is of the form $\frac{1}{0}$ - so you can't use L'Hopital.

Comment: @mich [Formatting math expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've missed a crucial fact about L'Hopital - it only works in specific cases.

Try it, for example, with: $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3+1}{x}$$

L'Hopital would tell you that it is $0$, but the value is $x^2+\frac{1}{x}$ which does not converge when $x\to 0$.

L'Hopital only works when the limits of the numerator and denominator are an "indeterminate form," which means one of:

$$\frac{-\infty}{-\infty},\frac{-\infty}{+\infty},\frac{+\infty}{-\infty},\frac{+\infty}{+\infty},\frac{0}{0}$$

Now:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}$$ has "form" $\frac{1}{0}$, which is not an indeterminate form.